# SQL Server CE timestamp handing

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

What is the formatting difference between:

```
DateTime datetimenow = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
```

and

```
long ticks = 634687637580000000;
DateTime createdTimestamp = new DateTime(ticks).ToLocalTime();
```

Which causes SQL Server CE to throw error

> There was an error in a part of the date format. [ Expression (if
>   known) =  ]

I am attempting to insert two timestamps into a SQL Server CE database. The current date time and a date time from the past. The current date and time (now) can be inserted into both target fields in the table, however when I use the `createdTimestamp` the error above is thrown.

The format when I review the locals in debug are **exactly** the same between the two.

The target fields are both of `datetime` data type.

Why might this error be thrown?

Edit:

I've just found it appears to only affect timestamps in the past. Now and future timestamps work fine.

Edit: adding code for SQL insertion.

Query is built dynamically by my own SQL Server CE class.

```
{INSERT timeline (TweetID,Author,TimestampOfTweet,TimestampOfCollected,TweetText) VALUES ('185941815562739713','twitterapi','15/12/2011 13:52:39','01/04/2012 15:58:58','TweetDeck access - Update : This issue has been resolved. http://t.co/2yub0tYL')}
```

Execution Code:

```
//Take built statement and apply to command text
cmd.CommandText = buildSqlStatement.ToString();

//execute insert
try
{
   cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
   sqlConn.Open();
   int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   string results = Convert.ToString(rows);
   return results;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   return ex.Message;
}
finally
{
   sqlConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you're *using* the value. Please show the interaction with SqlCE. If you're including the value directly, try using parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: Updated above. It's using my own SQLCE class.

Comment: Well to go back to my previous point, you should use a parameterized SQL statement. Then then driver would handle the conversion for you.

Comment: Really bad move, as @Jon Skeet says parameterised query is what you want. Passing things like dates and currencies as strings, is the first step on teh road to a disaster. For a start the date time format on the client could easily be different to that of the DBMS, so you can get irritating ambiguities like dd/mm/yy and mm/dd/yy.

Comment: Jon, Tony: Understood, I'll try a parametrised query. thanks.

Comment: @JonSkeet your suggestion worked great. Please add as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: @Damo: Done :) SQL injection is probably an even more important reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never include values directly in your SQL - always use *parameterized SQL* instead.

Benefits:

- Clean separation of "code" (the SQL) from data (the values)
- Protection against [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Avoids error-prone conversions such as in this question.